# Update State Provider from Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this periodic `useEffect` hook:

```js
const [state, dispatch] = useContext(NTTrackerContext);
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    dispatch({type: "REFRESH_APIS"});   // function that I'd like to use to update
    console.log(state.raceapi.racedata)
  }, 60000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [])
```

So, I have made a context provider, and I'd like to update it through the `dispatch` function. I want to use dispatch because I've written most of my code this way, but if there are better methods, please comment or add an answer.

In case you are wondering, yes, the function above is wrapped in `NTTrackerContextProvider`, code as provided below.

Context:

```js
export const NTTrackerContext = React.createContext([{}]);

const initialState = {
  user: {username: "", authenticated: false, email: "",},
  raceapi: {
    racedata: {'data': null}, racerlog: {}, racerdata: {}, teamdata: {},
  }
};

const nttrackerReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGGED_IN': {   // example of how I've written some parts of my reducer
      let {user, raceapi, ...etc} = state;
      let {userdata} = action;
      return {
        ...etc, user: {...user, ...userdata,}, raceapi: {...raceapi},
      }
    }
    default: return state;
  }
};

const NTTrackerContextProvider = props => {
  const initState = props.initState || initialState;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(nttrackerReducer, initState);
  return (
    <NTTrackerContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {props.children}
    </NTTrackerContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default NTTrackerContextProvider;
```

The APIs that I want to refresh is stored in the `raceapi` object. `racedata`, `racerlog`, etc. all have their own individual URLs; for instance, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racedata_json/` for `racedata`.

I have my initial values fetched using `fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racedata_json/"),` by this point, but I can't find a way to update the state using a function in my body *functional* component.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.